# Proper setup of docker compose with spring boot and postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file where i have two services the `flamup` service is used for building my spring boot application and links to a postgres image defined by the `db` service.

Here's the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'


volumes:
  postgres_data:

services:

  flamup:
    build: .
    container_name: flamup
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER=db
      - POSTGRES_DB=flamup
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db



  db:
    image: "postgres:9.6-alpine"
    container_name: postgres_container
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=flamup
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Here's the Dockerfile for the spring boot application

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-slim AS build
RUN mkdir -p workspace
WORKDIR workspace
COPY pom.xml /workspace
COPY src /workspace/src
COPY frontend /workspace/frontend
COPY data2.csv /workspace
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package
#RUN ./mvnw clean package -DskipTests

#FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I am using the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) for bootstrapping the frontend with the spring boot application. Everything works fine locally.

However when i try to run it via docker-compose i made some changes in the application-properties.yml

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always


spring:
  datasource:
    url : jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER}/${POSTGRES_DB}
    username : ${POSTGRES_USER}
    password : ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    show-sql: true

  session:
    store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      table-name: SPRING_SESSION
      initialize-schema: never
```

However the build get's failed everytime, because of this

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${DB_SERVER}
```

Things i have tried

- Hard coding the `DB_SERVER` variable and replacing with `localhost:5432` , `db` , `db:5432`. None of the seems to work.
- Adding depends on field in the `flamup` service.
- Adding networks field in both the services and connecting them via a bridge.
- Tried different versions of postgres and maven

Nothing seems to be the solution, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Answer (score 1):

So  a working solution to the problem ( though may not be that efficient ), is running the maven build by skipping the tests. Apparently hibernate results in running the JPA statements which results in failure of JDBC postgres exception as there is yet no container of postgres running.

Thus changing the dockerfile to

```
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean install -DskipTests=true
```

instead of

```
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package
```

caused in successful creation of the jar file which could be run as a docker container.